# VB.NET - When a button is pressed, do an action, wait a few seconds, and do another action

Tags: vb.net

I want to make it so when I press the button, it performs an action, waits a little bit and do another action. However, when I do this it doesn't do the first action until the Sleep has finished. I have also tried making a Background Thread but it can't access the ListBox. Can someone please explain how I can do this, and why my current one doesn't work? Thank you.

```
Private Sub Button10_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Thing1")
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Thing2")


End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it doesn't do the first action until the Sleep has finished

Not exactly. The action does happen, but the UI doesn't reflect the change until the UI thread becomes available to repaint the UI. However, because you put the UI thread to sleep, this does not happen.

Instead of sleeping, use [`Task.Delay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873(v=vs.110).aspx), which works similarly to a sleep, but the UI thread remains free to perform other work, including refreshing the UI:

```
Private Async Sub Button10_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Thing1")
    Await Task.Delay(500)
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Thing2")
End Sub
```

Notice that for this to work, you need to add `Async` to the method signature, and `Await` to the call to `Task.Delay()`.

To understand how the above code works, you may want to read [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/).